# why it is giving 403 Forbidden Error?

Tags: python, oracle, tornado

I am new in python i am trying to write code to fetch data from database while oracle to check whether user is register or not .This code is for web application But it is giving 403:Forbidden Error .I am unable identify whether problem in code  or it needs some more configuration I am working on windows 7.

---

```
      import logging
      import tornado.escape
      import tornado.ioloop
      import tornado.options
      import tornado.web
      import tornado.websocket
      import os.path
      import uuid
      import time
      import cx_Oracle

      from tornado.options import define, options

      define("port", default=5000, help="run on the given port", type=int)


      class Application(tornado.web.Application):
        def __init__(self):
            handlers = [(r"/", MainHandler),(r"/loggedin/page", UserIndex),]
            settings = dict(
            cookie_secret="__TODO:_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__",
            template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
            static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
             xsrf_cookies=True,
              autoescape=None,
               )
            tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)


        class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
          def get(self):
             self.render("mainPage.html")

        class UserIndex(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
           def post(self):
               userid=self.get_argument('userid')
               pwd=self.get_argument('pwd')
               con=cx_Oracle.connect('system','system','localhost:1521/XE')
               c=con.cursor()
               coun=c.execute("select count(*) from dmsuser where email= '%s' and pwd                          ='%s'" %(userid,pwd))
             con.close()
              if coun.fetchone()==(1,):
                 self.render('loggedinPage.html')
              else:
                 self.render('mainPage.html')   

       def main():
         tornado.options.parse_command_line()
         app = Application()
         app.listen(options.port)
         tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: Please indent your code in a consistend way. I.e. 4 spaces all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure without the template, but my guess is you're not including XSRF data in the POST request. Since you've set `xsrf_cookies=True` in the app configuration, you need to include the xsrf data in your form template:

```
<form method="post" action="...">
  {% module xsrf_form_html() %}
  ...
</form>
```